# Sorting in arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

While sorting an array 
for ex: A[5]={1,4,5,3,2}
the output must be 1,2,3,4,5 in ascending order.
in using the concept of bubble sorting
my output is 0,1,2,3,4
what would be the problem in my code

```
  int A[5]={1,5,3,2,4};
     for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
     for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
     if(A[j]>A[j+1])
     {
      int t=A[j];
      A[j]=A[j+1];
      A[j+1]=t;
     }
     }
    }
     for(i=0;i<5;i++)
     cout<<A[i];
```

Comment: Perhaps you have indexes mixed up with values?  We've no way of knowing because there's no example code provided.

Comment: unless you show us your code there is no way of knowing.

Answer (score 3):

You need to limit your inner loop to <4:

```
int A[5]={1,5,3,2,4};
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
        if(A[j]>A[j+1])
        {
           int t=A[j];
           A[j]=A[j+1];
           A[j+1]=t;
        } 
    }
}
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   cout<<A[i];
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the STL sort?

```
#include <algorithm>

std::sort(A, A+5);
```

Comment: The "+5" part is slippery thuogh... If `A` is an `array` or `vector`, then one can write `A.size()`, but for C-style array the preferred way probably is to `#define ARRAYSIZE(A) (sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]))` and then call `std::sort( A, A + ARRAYSIZE(A) );`

Comment: @ArunSaha: hardly. That breaks silently if `A` is a pointer. If you want to do something like this, use an inline template. Also, I'm not sure why this was downvoted. Seems a sensible answer in the general case. Of course, if the question is a part of a homework assignment or something, the STL version is probably out, but we don't know that.

Comment: @jaif: You are right, if `A` is a pointer then `ARRAYSIZE` does not work. But, that's changing the problem definition too much, in the problem `A` was **not** a pointer :). Also I mentioned `.size()` can be used whenever possible. BTW, it's not me who downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are printing `i` instead of `A[i]` in the printing loop, as in

```
for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
    cout << i << ",";          // by mistake, printing i instead of A[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are doing bubble sort, other then trying to learn it? It's one of the slower sorts.