# problem in coding

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting in arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794856/sorting-in-arrays)

```
int A[5]={1,5,3,2,4};
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
        if(A[j]>A[j+1])
        {
           int t=A[j];
           A[j]=A[j+1];
           A[j+1]=t;
        } 
    }
}
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   cout<<A[i];
```

The desired output must be 1,2,3,4,5
but my output is 0,1,2,3,4.
What's the problem in my code?

Comment: I've reformatted to make your code a bit more readable, I hope what I've done is OK?

Comment: That can't be the complete code as you can't have non-declaration statements outside of a function body.

Comment: This is exactly the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794856/sorting-in-arrays

Comment: Just for fun, have you actually executed the code you provide. It does actually output 12345. :)

Comment: @bjarkef this code triggers undefined behavior, so it **may** output 12345 if the value at A[5] is greater/equal to 5.

Comment: @ybungalobill Of cause, you're right.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, learn to indent properly. It isn't hard. Secondly, it looks like your making a sorting function.

The problem is that you are using the variable j for both for for loops. Don't. Change one to k, or another variable. I assume you are trying to reference the second j with j+1. This just adds 1 to j.

May I ask, do you have any coding experience?

And you should have specified what the problem was with your code, what you expected and what you got.

Comment: i have used i and j for the loops and not j for both the for loops

Comment: A[j+1] refers to the next element and not add 1 to that element

Comment: and this code is sorting an array in increasing order so i am swapping two elements at a time depending upon the if statement and to check every element in a sequential manner i have used that i loop

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are attempting Bubble sort, why don't you [read up on it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) . I'm sure you can get it working yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) instead, works great!

```
int A[5]={1,5,3,2,4};
vector<int> vec(A, A+5);

sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Comment: I think this is cheat as the author seems to learn how to sort himself :)

Comment: i have just asked what is the problem in my code and whay it is not giving the desired output don't think negative Benoit

Comment: it's not cheating unless there are rules stating he is not allowed to use it. :) And it is the easiest way I would think.. Some wheels don't need reinventing

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit your inner loop to <4:

```
int A[5]={1,5,3,2,4};
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
        if(A[j]>A[j+1])
        {
           int t=A[j];
           A[j]=A[j+1];
           A[j+1]=t;
        } 
    }
}
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   cout<<A[i];
```

Comment: after changing j with 4 the output is 2 3 4 5 0

Comment: Please update your question with the new code. Did you copy and paste my code?

Answer (score 0):

Your program will not produce that output. It will die at A[j+1] when j == 4. In the last loop you need to write for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++). Secondly, your logic doesn't have much sense. If you want to sort the array this is the code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < 5; j++){
        if(A[j] < A[i])
        {
            int t = A[j];
            A[j] = A[i];
            A[i] = t;
        } 
    }
}
```